# HTML Form Password value will not save to phpMyAdmin database, all the other fields are fine

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords

I made a registration form that takes email, username, firstname, etc...Only Password will not store in the database upon submission.

The field is declared correctly in the HTML file, password is set to varchar, all the other variables post but I can't pinpoint why not this password field.

Please find below my set up:(php 5.6.39)
[image]

So i corrected the "." after Username on line 25, but now it's weird.
it still doesn't post to the then actually outputs my error message "First Name and Last Name is a required field and cannot be blank."

```
    $required = array('Email','FirstName','LastName', 'Username', 'Password');
     // Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty 
    $error = false;
    foreach($required as $field){
      if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
          $error = true; 
      } 
    } 
    if ($error) {
        echo "First Name and Last Name is a required field and 
    cannot be blank."; 
   } else {
        echo " Awesome, you filled it all in! ";
   }
```

even when all fields are submitted

Answer (score 1):

Hey you put full stop instead of comma after UserName :

'Username','Password'

Comment: good catch! I did correct it, and it still doesn't post to the db. weird, it actually outputs my error message "First Name and Last Name is a required field and cannot be blank."

$required = array('Email','FirstName','LastName', 'Username', 'Password');

// Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
    if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $error = true;
    }
}

if ($error) {
    echo "First Name and Last Name is a required field and cannot be blank.";
} else {
    echo " Awesome, you filled it all in! ";
}

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

```
$uname = (!empty($_POST['UserName'])) ? $_POST['UserName'] : $uname;
$pword = (!empty($_POST['Password'])) ? $_POST['Password'] : $pword;
```

Warning for Sql Injection
Don't use direct $_POST try to sanitize it first,

Comment: thanks for your answer! will try this tomorrow, just started this class so we’re pretty basic. do i just replace lines 21 and 22 with this but also keep lines 19 and 20?

Comment: With the reference of @Harish please update your code and yes replace only 21 and 22

Comment: Updated, and replaced with your code, still doesn't post :(

Comment: are you getting an error or something else? can you share your insert code here? Can you try to echo all the $_POST & variables before line no 24?

Comment: thanks for the swift reply... I have this :

    $required = array('Email','FirstName','LastName', 'Username', 'Password');
  // Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty 
$error = false; foreach($required as $field)
 { if (empty($_POST[$field])) { $error = true; } 
} if ($error) { echo "First Name and Last Name is a required field and 
cannot be blank."; } else { echo " Awesome, you filled it all in! ";

no error, but it echoes "First Name and Last Name is a required field and cannot be blank"

Comment: oops insert statement is :
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
VALUES ('$email','$fname', '$lname', '$uname', '$pword')";

Comment: Try this : $sql = "INSERT INTO users (EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES ('".$email."','".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$uname."', '".$pword."')";

Comment: oo i thought it worked, but it's not storing Username

Answer (score 0):

```html
$uname = (isset($_SESSION['Username']) ? $_SESSION['Username'] : NULL);
$pword = (isset($_SESSION['Password']) ? $_SESSION['Password'] : NULL);
$uname = (isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : $uname);
$pword = (isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : $pword);
```